# Output of dividing int64_t by uint64_t

Tags: c++

Can someone help me understand the reason behind output being 542551296275775048 even though I am assigning the final output to a int64_t?

I was expecting the output as -9799999

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int64_t a = -333199966; 
    uint64_t b = 34;

    int64_t temp = a/b;

    cout << temp << endl;
}

Output : 542551296275775048
```

Comment: What you do with the result is irrelevant.

Comment: This is not C language. C != C++ please remove the tag.

Comment: To get the output you want, do `a / (int64_t)b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `Signed` with `Unsigned` in your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int64_t a = -333199966; 
    uint64_t b = 34;

    int64_t temp = a / (int64_t)b; // here is the difference

    cout << temp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is [Why Not Mix Signed and Unsigned Values in C/C++?](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/268)

Answer (score 3):

There is an implicit conversion from `int64_t` to `uint64_t` before the division.

Answer (score 1):

It's a C++ specification standard. Here's the [source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic). To quote from it:

> Otherwise, if the unsigned operand's conversion rank is greater or equal to the conversion rank of the signed operand, the signed operand is converted to the unsigned operand's type.